# SQLite create Table not working without any error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I tried to create a database and create one table in it. The database is being created but not the table.it doesn't show any error and also am not able to insert the value into it.I want to create a table and insert the data recieved from the user but the data is not able to add to database, neither it shows any errors.The code is as follows:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAMETRY + "(" +
                    COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + COL_PHONE + " TEXT " + ")";`enter code here`
            db.execSQL(q);
    }
    @Override

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP table if exist "+TABLE_NAMETRY);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name,String no)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentvalue = new ContentValues();
        contentvalue.put(COL_NAME,name);
        contentvalue.put(COL_PHONE,no);
       long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAMETRY,null,contentvalue);
        if(result==-1)
        return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DataBaseHelper mydb;
    EditText name,no;
    Button b1;
    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mydb=new DataBaseHelper(this);

        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.no);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Adding Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                AddData();
            }
        });
    }
    public void AddData()
    {
        boolean check= mydb.insertData(name.getText().toString(),no.getText().toString());
        if(check==true)
            t1.setText("data submitted");
        else
            t1.setText("data not submitted");

    }
}
```

Comment: Try use method `insertOrThrow` instead `insert` in line with `db.insert(TABLE_NAMETRY,null,contentvalue)`. And say what you get.

Comment: `db.execSQL("DROP table if exist "+TABLE_NAMETRY);` it's actually EXIST**S**.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably the helper is creating the table (onCreate) and then delete it (onUpgrade).

Here how I create my helper, take notice of the databaseVersion, as it is important when the (onUpgrade) is executed

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private final static String databaseName = "Your_DB_Name";
private final static int databaseVersion = 13;

DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { // Do Create Your Table Here }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int Old_Version, int New_Version) { //Delete Your tables here if they exists}
```